# backtransform `scale()` for plotting

Tags: r

I have a explanatory variable that is centered using `scale()` that is used to predict a response variable:

```
d <- data.frame(
  x=runif(100),
  y=rnorm(100)
)

d <- within(d, s.x <- scale(x))

m1 <- lm(y~s.x, data=d)
```

I'd like to plot the predicted values, but using the original scale of `x` rather than the centered scale. Is there a way to sort of backtransform or reverse scale `s.x`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Take a look at:

```
attributes(d$s.x)
```

You can use the attributes to unscale:

```
d$s.x * attr(d$s.x, 'scaled:scale') + attr(d$s.x, 'scaled:center')
```

For example:

```
> x <- 1:10
> s.x <- scale(x)

> s.x
            [,1]
 [1,] -1.4863011
 [2,] -1.1560120
 [3,] -0.8257228
 [4,] -0.4954337
 [5,] -0.1651446
 [6,]  0.1651446
 [7,]  0.4954337
 [8,]  0.8257228
 [9,]  1.1560120
[10,]  1.4863011
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 5.5
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 3.02765

> s.x * attr(s.x, 'scaled:scale') + attr(s.x, 'scaled:center')
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    2
 [3,]    3
 [4,]    4
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    6
 [7,]    7
 [8,]    8
 [9,]    9
[10,]   10
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 5.5
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 3.02765
```

Comment: nice response +1  Should the `attr(s.x, 'scaled:center')` be `attr(d$s.x, 'scaled:center')`?

Comment: @TylerRinker Thanks, it should.  Fixed!

Answer (score 16):

For a data frame or matrix:

```
set.seed(1)
x = matrix(sample(1:12), ncol= 3)
xs = scale(x, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

x.orig = t(apply(xs, 1, function(r)r*attr(xs,'scaled:scale') + attr(xs, 'scaled:center')))

print(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    2    3
[2,]    5    7    1
[3,]    6   10   11
[4,]    9   12    8

print(x.orig)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    2    3
[2,]    5    7    1
[3,]    6   10   11
[4,]    9   12    8
```

Be careful when using functions like `identical()`:

```
print(x - x.orig)
     [,1] [,2]         [,3]
[1,]    0    0 0.000000e+00
[2,]    0    0 8.881784e-16
[3,]    0    0 0.000000e+00
[4,]    0    0 0.000000e+00

identical(x, x.orig)
# FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me to calculate back the cluster *centers* after a kMeans clustering with a scaled matrix. `centers <- t(apply(clustering$centers, 1, function(r) r * attr(scaled_mat, 'scaled:scale') + attr(scaled_mat, 'scaled:center')))` The accepted answer didn't.

Comment: I am on your exact same task @kadrian but why this function does not work on my scaled data??

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, not the one that adds all. So the idea here in this elegant solution is that you multiply the matrix with the scale vector and add the means *row-wise* before you flip it to get the original matrix right, brilliant!

Answer (score 9):

I felt like this should be a proper function, here was my attempt at it:

```
#' Reverse a scale
#'
#' Computes x = sz+c, which is the inverse of z = (x - c)/s 
#' provided by the \code{scale} function.
#' 
#' @param z a numeric matrix(like) object
#' @param center either NULL or a numeric vector of length equal to the number of columns of z  
#' @param scale  either NULL or a a numeric vector of length equal to the number of columns of z
#'
#' @seealso \code{\link{scale}}
#'  mtcs <- scale(mtcars)
#'  
#'  all.equal(
#'    unscale(mtcs), 
#'    as.matrix(mtcars), 
#'    check.attributes=FALSE
#'  )
#'  
#' @export
unscale <- function(z, center = attr(z, "scaled:center"), scale = attr(z, "scaled:scale")) {
  if(!is.null(scale))  z <- sweep(z, 2, scale, `*`)
  if(!is.null(center)) z <- sweep(z, 2, center, `+`)
  structure(z,
    "scaled:center"   = NULL,
    "scaled:scale"    = NULL,
    "unscaled:center" = center,
    "unscaled:scale"  = scale
  )
}
```

Comment: And for fun, I've added this to the github version of the `stackoverflow` package.

Comment: Luis torgo made a function (available in `DMwR`) for unscaling, too: [https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DMwR/versions/0.4.1/topics/unscale](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DMwR/versions/0.4.1/topics/unscale)

Comment: It doesn't look like `DMwR` has been updated in six years.

Comment: Great contribution, thank you! Imagine not having to source this code or install a package to undo a base R function :)

Answer (score 7):

tl;dr:

```
unscaled_vals <- xs + attr(xs, 'scaled:scale') + attr(xs, 'scaled:center')
```

- where `xs` is a scaled object created by `scale(x)`

---

Just for those trying to make a bit of sense about this:

**How R scales**:

The [`scale`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/scale) function performs both scaling and centering by default.

- Of the two, the function performs `centering` first.

Centering is achieved by default by subtracting the mean of all `!is.na` input values from each value:

```
data - mean(data, rm.na = T)
```

Scaling is achieved via:

```
sqrt( ( sum(x^2) ) / n - 1)
```

where `x` is the set of all `!is.na` values to scale and `n` = `length(x)`.

- Importantly, though, when `center =T` in `scale`, `x` is not the original set of data, but the *already centered* data.

  So if `center = T` (the default), the scaling function is *really* calculating:

  ```
   sqrt( ( sum( (data - mean(data, rm.na = T))^2) ) / n - 1)
  ```

  - Note: [when `center = T`] this is the same as taking the standard deviation: `sd(data)`.

**How to Unscale**:

*Explanation*:

1. first multiply by scaling factor:

   ```
   y = x * sqrt( ( sum( (x - mean(x , na.rm = T))^2) ) / (length(x) - 1))
   ```
2. then add back mean:

   ```
   y + mean(x , na.rm = T)
   ```

Obviously you need to know the mean of the original set of data for this *manual* approach to *truly* be useful, but I place it here for conceptual sake.

Luckily, as previous answers have shown, the "centering" value (i.e., the *mean*) is located in the attributes of a `scale` object, so this approach can be simplified to:

*How to do in R*:

```
unscaled_vals <- xs + attr(xs, 'scaled:scale') + attr(xs, 'scaled:center')
```

- where `xs` is a scaled object created by `scale(x)`.

Comment: In  `unscaled_vals <- xs + attr(xs, 'scaled:scale') + attr(xs, 'scaled:center')` you are adding the deviation instead of multiplying. I tried to edit, but it doesn't let me because it's too small of a change xD

Answer (score 6):

I came across this problem and I think I found a simpler solution using linear algebra.

```
# create matrix like object
a <- rnorm(1000,5,2)
b <- rnorm(1000,7,5) 

df <- cbind(a,b)

# get center and scaling values 
mean <- apply(df, 2, mean)
sd <- apply(df, 2, sd)

# scale data
s.df <- scale(df, center = mean, scale = sd)

#unscale data with linear algebra 
us.df <- t((t(s.df) * sd) + mean)
```

Comment: This is handy in the common situation where only a subset of a dataframe's columns have been scaled.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but why wouldn't you just do this:

```
plot(d$x, predict(m1, d))
```

As an easier way than manually using the attributes from the scaled object, DMwR has a function for this: [`unscale`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DMwR/versions/0.4.1/topics/unscale).  It works like this:

```
d <- data.frame(
  x=runif(100)
)

d$y <- 17 + d$x * 12

s.x <- scale(d$x)

m1 <- lm(d$y~s.x)

library(DMwR)
unsc.x <- unscale(d$x, s.x)
plot(unsc.x, predict(m1, d))
```

Importantly, the second argument of `unscale` needs to have something with the attributes of `'scaled:scale'` and `'scaled:center'`

Answer (score 1):

Just inspired by Fermando´s answer, but unscaling line with less code:

```
set.seed(1)
x = matrix(sample(1:12), ncol= 3)
xs = scale(x, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
center <- attr(xs,"scaled:center")
scale <- attr(xs,"scaled:scale")
x.orig <- t(t(xs) * scale + center) # code is less here

print(x)
[1,]    9    2    6
[2,]    4    5   11
[3,]    7    3   12
[4,]    1    8   10

print(x.orig)
[1,]    9    2    6
[2,]    4    5   11
[3,]    7    3   12
[4,]    1    8   10
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 5.25 4.50 9.75
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 3.50 2.65 2.63
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that an easy way to reverse the `scale()` function is to call twice back the `scale()` function:

```html
X_scaled <- scale(X,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE)
X_reversed <- scale(X_scaled,center=FALSE,scale=1/attr(X_scaled,'scaled:scale'))
X_reversed <- scale(X_reversed,center=-attr(X_scaled,'scaled:center'),scale=FALSE)
```

If you don't mind calling a function within the arguments of a function (which I do mind), you could end up with the following solution:

```html
X_scaled <- scale(X,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE)
X_reversed <- scale(scale(X_scaled,center=FALSE,scale=1/attr(X_scaled,'scaled:scale')),
                    center=-attr(X_scaled,'scaled:center'),scale=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party. But here is a useful tool to scale/unscale data in array format.

**Example:**

```
> (data <- array(1:8, c(2, 4)))            # create data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    5    7
[2,]    2    4    6    8
> obj <- Scale(data)                       # create object
> (data_scaled <- obj$scale(data))         # scale data
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] -0.7071068 -0.7071068 -0.7071068 -0.7071068
[2,]  0.7071068  0.7071068  0.7071068  0.7071068
> (obj$unscale(data_scaled))               # unscale scaled data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    5    7
[2,]    2    4    6    8

## scale or unscale another dataset
## using the same mean/sd parameters
> (data2 <- array(seq(1, 24, 2), c(3, 4))) # create demo data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    7   13   19
[2,]    3    9   15   21
[3,]    5   11   17   23
> (data2_scaled <- obj$scale(data2))       # scale data
           [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] -0.7071068  4.949747 10.60660 16.26346
[2,]  2.1213203  7.778175 13.43503 19.09188
[3,]  4.9497475 10.606602 16.26346 21.92031
> (obj$unscale(data2_scaled))              # unscale scaled data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    7   13   19
[2,]    3    9   15   21
[3,]    5   11   17   23
```

**Function** `Scale()`:

```
Scale <- function(data, margin=2, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE){
    stopifnot(is.array(data), is.numeric(data),
              any(mode(margin) %in% c("integer", "numeric")),
              length(margin) < length(dim(data)),
              max(margin) <= length(dim(data)),
              min(margin) >= 1,
              !any(duplicated(margin)),
              is.logical(center), length(center)==1,
              is.logical(scale), length(scale)==1,
                  !(isFALSE(center) && isFALSE(scale)))
    margin <- as.integer(margin)

    m <- if(center) apply(data, 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE) else NULL
    s <- if(scale)  apply(data, 2, sd, na.rm=TRUE) else NULL
    ldim <- length(dim(data))
    cdim <- dim(data)[margin]
    data <- NULL # don't store the data

    Scale <- function(data){
        stopifnot(is.array(data), is.numeric(data),
                  length(dim(data)) == ldim,
                  dim(data)[margin] == cdim)
        if(center)
            data <- sweep(data, margin, m, `-`)
        if(scale)
            data <- sweep(data, margin, s, `/`)
        data
    }

    Unscale <- function(data){
        stopifnot(is.array(data), is.numeric(data),
                  length(dim(data)) == ldim,
                  dim(data)[margin] == cdim)
        if(scale)
            data <- sweep(data, margin, s, `*`)
        if(center)
            data <- sweep(data, margin, m, `+`)
        data
    }
    list(scale=Scale, unscale=Unscale, mean=m, sd=s)
}
```

**Note:**
`data.frame`s are not support yet.