# Backtransform Scale() function in R

Tags: r

I have a question concerning the `scale()` function.

I scale a matrix and I want to understand how to scale back, so I tried to make in the following way:

```
datatest <- read.xls("training.xlsx")
data_train<-as.matrix(datatest)

scaled.data_train <- scale(data_train, center= TRUE, scale=TRUE)
training <- sample(nrow(scaled.data_train), 80)
```

Xtraining <- scaled.data_train[training, ] # keeps 80 from 98 records
Xtest <- scaled.data_train[-training, ]

afterwards I made a prediction based on Xtraining and I obtain Predicted_Xtest

How can I unscale Predicted_Xtest?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has been answered before [backtransform `scale()` for plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287545/backtransform-scale-for-plotting)

```
t(apply(scaled.data_train, 1, function(r)r*attr(scaled.data_train,'scaled:scale') + attr(scaled.data_train, 'scaled:center')))
```

Need to apply scaling across each column.