# Model complex equation in R

Tags: r, math, equation, differential-equations, equation-solving

I have the following model:

[image: $y(t) = C + A_{0}\exp^{(-\sigma t)}\cos(\omega_dt+\phi)$]

which I've coded in R as:

```
function(t,C,Ao,s,wd,ph) C + Ao * exp(-s*t) * cos(wd*t + ph)
```

I want to use this equation to form a predictive model.

However, I can't figure out how to either successfully run or plot this equation.

- I tried `nls` but got various errors (including those that warned me about a `singular gradient`.

I looked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13053/80624) but I don't see where to go form here given that my model doesn;t seem to work.

**How can I model and graph this function in R?**

---

**What I tried:**

```
LTI.func <- function(t,C,Ao,s,wd,ph) C + Ao * exp(-s*t) * cos(wd * t + ph)
mod <- nls(Y ~ LTI.func(t = I(scale(t)), C, Ao, s, wd, ph), 
           data = dat, 
           start = list(C = 1, Ao = 1, s = 1, w = 1, ph = 1))
```

I had no idea what `starts` to select, so I tried a bunch of random ones, which resulted in errors. Even when I picked starts guided by the y(t) ~ t trend I could see, I always got some kind of error:

> ```
> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
>   singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
>
> Error in nls(Y ~ LTI.func(I(scale(t)), C, Ao, s, wd, ph), data = dat  : 
>   singular gradient
> ```

**Update:**

Here is an example set of data:

```
dat <- data.frame(t = c(72, 25, 10, 88, 67, 63, 34, 41, 75, 13, 59, 8, 30, 52, 21),
                  Y = c(108.7, 157.5, 17.7, 175, 246.8, 233.5, 208.6, 246.5, 126.5, 
                        45.5, 214.1, 4.9, 184, 239.2, 113.3))
```

Comment: Which of those values are data and which are values you want to estimate? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show your code attempts.

Comment: Re how to plot the equation: `curve(f(x, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))`

Comment: do you have the values of `y(t)` and `t`?

Comment: @Onyambu I have y(t) and t for known samples. I know nothing else (except, obviously, the graphical appearance of the y(t) ~ t relationship.

Comment: Then you need to give some dataframe for y and t for someone to have an example of what you are talking about

Comment: My bad, guys. I'm half asleep. I've updated with code and examples

Answer (score 1):

This showed up in the close queue but seemed to me to be reasonably well-formed, if poorly checked for consistency of parameter names. Here's my shot at a solution. I've tried first changing the argument to the function to `x` and when that didn't work tried tweaking the starting values. Eventually, I decided to scale the data argument:

```
LTI.func <- function(x,C,Ao,s,wd,ph) {C + Ao * exp(-s*x) * cos(wd * x + ph)}
 mod <- nls(Y ~ LTI.func(x=t , C, Ao, s, wd, ph), data=data.frame(scale(dat)), 
                     start=list(C = 0,Ao = -1,s = 1,wd = 1,ph = 0))
 mod
#-------------
Nonlinear regression model
  model: Y ~ LTI.func(x = t, C, Ao, s, wd, ph)
   data: data.frame(scale(dat))
        C        Ao         s        wd        ph 
 0.288729 -0.986426  0.517128  2.002040  2.756004 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1.53608

Number of iterations to convergence: 18 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 0.0000038776
```

Whether that would be a useful "solution" will require back-transforming and plotting the results against the original values or perhaps plotting the transformed coordinates against the theoretical. I wasn't surprised that the A0 value was less than zero. It certainly looked from the data that the trend was upward and  `exp(-s*x)` would generally be downward if `s*x` were positive.

Comment: Thanks for this! I got your approach to work. However, (not due to a lack in your answer by any means) changing the parameters either does nothing to the model line (i.e., _ala_ `lines(x, predict...)`) or produces an error. I haven't quite wrapped my head around that yet. Why would changes either fail or do nothing? I threw the equation into excel to easily watch prediction values change as I changed parameters, so I know the equation itself can be more plastic. Is this an `nls` issue???

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "changing the parameters". (No code.) Are we talking about the starting values? If so, why would it bother you that changing them has no effect?

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant the starting values. It only bothers me because I don;t understand why that's the case. (I'll be honest, I'm < 5 hrs deep into learning/workign with non-linear models like this, so I'm just a noob when it comes to understanding anything :p)

Comment: The starting values are only designed to get the search started in a "region" where there might be a reasonably good possibility of finding a solution "nearby" without having to cross any sections of parameter space where the function "blows up" (goes to `Inf` or `-Inf`. So it's actually good practice to change them around and your hope is that `nls` would still end up "in the same place".

Comment: Also, I just found a neat way to scale data without having to scale the whole data.frame (which is a problem for non-numeric columns in the data): `transform(dat, t = scale(t), Y = scale(Y))`.

Comment: For my own reference (and others) [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10287545/4581200) discusses back-transforming a `scale`'d object in R.

Comment: As long as you make an assignment that should work. The way I did it gives `nls` a scaled matrix object. Could also assign `data.frame(scale(dat))`. Also probably would be safer to use `center= FALSE` since sometimes functions will fail with negative numbers. The information about back-scaling would also be available at `?scale`.