# Unscaling the output of an ANN

Tags: r, neural-network

I have scaled my data so that the minimum takes the value 0 and the maximum the value 1. I have done this using the rescale function, which is part of the scale package in R. I then run this data through an ANN and compute the predictions of this ANN. Obviously the output will still be scaled according to the minimum and maximum of the input.

I believe there should be a way to unscale this dating using simple algebra but my maths isn't the best.

Let's say the input was `x.input`, and my output id `x.output`.

```
range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
x.input <- range01(x)
```

This is what the rescale function is doing.

How would I go about writing a function to reverse the transformation?

Thanks

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287545/backtransform-scale-for-plotting

Comment: without the min(x) and max(x) values stored somewhere it wouldn't be possible