# Unscale predicted value for Neural Network (Keras package)

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

#### partition of data

```
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(bronx_data), replace = T, prob = c(.7,.3))
train <- bronx_data[ind==1,2:11]
test <- bronx_data[ind==2,2:11]
train_target <- bronx_data[ind==1,1]
test_target <- bronx_data[ind==2,1]
```

#### normalize my data**

```
m <- colMeans(train)
s <- apply(train, 2, sd)
train <- scale(train, center = m, scale = s)
test <- scale(test, center = m, scale = s) # use same mean and sd obtained form train data
```

### Model

**This is my model**

```
library(keras)
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
        layer_dense(units = 5, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(10)) %>%
        layer_dense(units = 1)
```

**I get good output but the problem I am having is un-scaling the data. Someone please HELP.**  I am new coder. 
I've tried

```
unscale(vals, norm.data, col.ids)
```

and got the following error

> Error in scale.default(data, center = FALSE, scale = 1/scale) : length of 'scale' must equal the number of columns of 'x'

Comment: Hi! Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287545/backtransform-scale-for-plotting ?