# Backtransforming response for plotting allEffects

Tags: r, plot

I have fitted a few models using `glmer` from the`lme4` package and did model selection with `MuMIn::dredge()` followed by model averaging. My response is frequency of occurrence of an animal in front of camera traps (continuous, number of photos per 100 hours of camera time); the predictors are minimum distances from a camera trap to landscape categories in meters, sometimes with an interaction with the day phase (day/night).

The response shows Gamma-distribution, but to make the model work I had to transform my response by adding 1, as the Gamma distribution can't handle non-positive data and quite a few of my data points were zeros as shown in this histogram:

[image: in this histogram]

Also, I had to scale the predictors, otherwise I got convergence warnings like

> Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio - Rescale variables?

I did this with `scale(..., center = TRUE)`.

My model formula looks like this:

```
mod <- glmer(Species_Frequency ~ scaled_Minimal_Distance1 + 
   scaled_Minimal_Distance2 + 
   (scaled_Minimal_Distance3 * Dayphase), 
data = data, 
na.action = na.fail, 
family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

Now I want to plot the results of `mod`  using `plot(allEffects(mod))`.

For plotting, I am backscaling my predictors in the `allEffects`-object by accessing

`allEffects(mod)[["scaled_Minimal_Distance1"]][["x"]][["scaled_Minimal_Distance1"]]` and doing as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287545/backtransform-scale-for-plotting). I would also like to back-transform my response, to make the plot more understandable. Otherwise one would always have to keep in mind that 1 on the y-axis is actually 0, 2 is 1 etc. Can someone help me on how to do this, as I hit a roadblock and can't seem to figure it out myself.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "frequency of occurrence"? You seem to say that the responses are 0,1,2,... which you transform to 1,2,3,... This seems more like number of occurrences (and counts are discrete while the Gamma distribution is continuous).

Comment: What is the ratio of zero to non-zero? It might be worth looking at a Poisson or Negative Binomial distribution, they have ways of dealing with zeroes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model

Comment: Please see my edits. I have misformulated this, the "1 is 0 etc" thing described the values on the y-axis, my frequency is continuous.
@hrabel I have added a histogram of my non-transformed data. I tried poisson, but as it is non-integer, it didn't work. I should maybe add, that I am quite unexperienced in statistics.