# Elegant way to invert tranform recipes steps (normalize and log)?

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

What is the most elegant way to transform back `outcome` (in this case it's `mpg`) column that was transformed by recipes?
The solution can be general (if exists or only for `log` and `normalize` steps (as coded below).

Links that might be useful:
The general solution was discussed [here](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/264) but I don't think it's already implemented.
Solution for R function `scale` is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287545/backtransform-scale-for-plotting) but I'm not sure if I can help with it in this case.

```
library(recipes)

data <- tibble(mtcars) %>% 
    select(cyl, mpg)

rec <- recipe(mpg ~ ., data = data) %>%
    step_log(all_numeric()) %>%
    step_normalize(all_numeric()) %>%
    prep()

data_baked <- bake(rec, new_data = data)

# model fitting, predictions, etc...

# how to invert/transform back predictions (estimates) and true outcomes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to get back out any values you need to from recipe transformations [is to `tidy()` the recipe](https://www.tmwr.org/recipes.html#tidy-a-recipe) and then use dplyr verbs to get out what you need.

```r
library(recipes)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'recipes'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     step

data <- tibble(mtcars) %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg)

rec <- recipe(mpg ~ ., data = data) %>%
  step_log(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric(), id = "normalize_num") %>%
  prep()
```

There are **two** ways to get out recipe steps, and then you can `tidy()` with an argument:

```r
## notice that you can identify steps by `number` or `id`
tidy(rec)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   number operation type      trained skip  id           
#>    <int> <chr>     <chr>     <lgl>   <lgl> <chr>        
#> 1      1 step      log       TRUE    FALSE log_LYuaY    
#> 2      2 step      normalize TRUE    FALSE normalize_num

## choose by number
tidy(rec, number = 1)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   terms  base id       
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>    
#> 1 cyl    2.72 log_LYuaY
#> 2 mpg    2.72 log_LYuaY
## choose by id, which we set above (otherwise it has random id like log)
tidy(rec, id = "normalize_num")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   terms statistic value id           
#>   <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>        
#> 1 cyl   mean      1.78  normalize_num
#> 2 mpg   mean      2.96  normalize_num
#> 3 cyl   sd        0.309 normalize_num
#> 4 mpg   sd        0.298 normalize_num
```

Once we know which step we want, we can use dplyr verbs to get out exactly which value we want to transform back, like the mean of `mpg`.

```r
## extract out value
tidy(rec, id = "normalize_num") %>%
  filter(terms == "mpg", statistic == "mean") %>%
  pull(value)
#>      mpg 
#> 2.957514
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>