# Does dplyr have an easy way to un-standardize data?

Tags: r, dplyr

I know I can easily standardize data using dplyer with the code `df %>% mutate_at(c('var1'), ~(scale(.) %>% as.vector))`, but is there some way to "un-standardize" the data after I've played with it?

Comment: If you do `as.vector` you're stripping away the metadata and the process is not reversible. For example both `as.vector(scale(1:3))` and `as.vector(scale(1:3*4-2))` return the same scaled values, but they start out as different vectors. The process is not uniquely invertible. If you keep the attributes, there are existing "unscale" options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287545/backtransform-scale-for-plotting

Answer (score 0):

so long as you keep the original it is easy

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(scale_mpg = scale(mpg),
         unscale = mean(mpg) + scale_mpg * sd(mpg))
```

Comment: But if you kept the original, why would you bother unscaling? Just use `mpg` directly again. No need to mess with the scaled versions.